# CSS "clear: both" not working, element keeps staying on the side of each other

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm playing around with some code. But, I have one question:

Why the `clear: both` command under the `span` tag, is not working?

If you run the code, you can see that the `span` elements (represented by a cyan color) are at the same line as the `div` elements. I don't understand why this is happening.
I mean, I know workarounds that can fix the problem, but I'm trying to understand why it isn't working at this specific situation?

Thank you!!! =)

```css
span{
    height: 50px;
    width: 75px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgb(0, 255, 255);
    clear: both;
}

div{
    height: 100px;
    width: 34%; /*ocupa 34% da tela*/
    background: greenyellow;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}

p{
    background: rgb(225, 11, 233);
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
    <section>Olá hello</section> 
<hr>

    <span> Oi</span>
    <span> Oi 2</span>
    <span> Oi 3</span>
    <div> Hello</div>
    <div> Hello 2 </div>
    <div> Hello 3</div>
    <p> Hi</p>
    <p> Hi 2</p>
    <p> Hi 3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps use one of the clearfix recipes? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: span aren't floating so nothing to clear after them. Make them floating and see the result

Comment: Try CSS Grids or Flexbox instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clear: both;` only is relevant for elements that are floated, which is not the case for your `span` (those spans are inline-blocks, but that's another thing, `clear` has no effect on inline-blocks)